# Automatically generate buttons in PDF

Tags: pdf, automation, pdf-generation

I am looking for some creative ideas for making numbers clickable in PDF file. The PDF file is very large, and each page contains many numbers in the following format:

[00-00]

What is the best route to explore? Right now, the only idea that I have brainstormed is:

- The PDF is created from Adobe InDesign. Perhaps "hooking" into InDesign before the PDF is created

I am looking to do this in a way that will be very automated, as there are a lot of numbers on a lot of pages.

Thanks!

Comment: It can be any version...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's various clever things you can do with grep styles in CS4 and CS5 - might be worth a go. There's also a lot of [scripting you can do in InDesign using JavaScript](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.adobe.com%2Fproducts%2Findesign%2Fscripting%2Fpdfs%2FInDesignCS3_ScriptingGuide_JS.pdf&ei=A4x-TOWsNJi8jAfZ7NnyCg&usg=AFQjCNFzT2DRh3Nuke-xHYGSTrWKGSQG6w) - I'd start from there.